# Scale embed flash to browser

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm using an embed flash player in a web page and I want to scale it to browser window.
When I put "height: 100%" in the flash parameters, I get a blank page.
This is the code of the page :

```
    SlideShowPro({
        target: "slideshow",
        xmlFilePath: "galeries/images.php?album=1",
        width: "100%",
        height: 740,

        params: {
            allowfullscreen: true,
            wmode: "transparent",
        },

        mobile: {
            auto: true,
            showBackButton: true,
            showInfoButton: false,
        },
        flashvars: {
            paramXMLPath: "galeries/m/params/ice.xml",
            contentScale: "Crop to Fit",
        }
    });
```

and this is the style I'm using :

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

For the width it's OK but when I change the height from 740 to "100%" or when I delete it, I have a blank page.

Can you help me please to fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your movie inside a div and set the div's width and height to 100%. The Flash movie will scale if your JS code is working properly.